# Internet speed perhaps not concentrating?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bandwidth

Roughly I know bandwidth as the internet speed(e.g. 512kbps, 1mbps etc);

Even though the bandwidth I have purchased is 1mbps, my downloads are usually(mostly always) stuck at a 100kbps speeds. Is it that my machine is limiting it to this speed? Can I make it concentrate to download at more speed that my ISP is providing me? E.g. 300-400 kbps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 1Mbps is about 125kBps.

That is, you pay for 1 mega**bit** per second, from your ISP.

You download at 100 kilo**bytes** per second, which is actually pretty good considering overheads and such.

**Note:**

A **b** is generally used to indicate **bit**

A **B** is generally used to indicate **byte**

**M** ("mega") and **k** (kilo) are SI-prefixes (explained in [Wikipedia's SI-Prefix-Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) ).

Comment: `No, 1Mbps is about 125kbps.`
1 Mbps (1 Megabit per second) != 125 kbps (125 kilobit per second).
as you wrote yourself,
a small "b" means "bit",
a capitalised "B" means "Byte".

So 1 Mbps = 125 kBps.

Comment: Whoops, you're right!

Comment: 1mbps is a millibit per second, which can download one byte in a mere two hours and 13 minutes. If there's no parity or check bit.

Comment: Hey while we're being pedantic (don't get me wrong, I like it), most file download and file copy UIs that report speeds in Bytes usually report in KibiBytes, not kiloBytes (but they still use the deprecated programmer shorthand of misusing SI units for this). So 1Mbps is about 119 KiBps.

Comment: @djsmiley2k, I came to this confusion a bit later, but, can we connect a device to the USB and use the PC and Device to sort of boost their download time with a sort of series connection?

Comment: AFAIK: no. I think that you're thinking about [802.3ad - Link Aggregation](https://serverfault.com/a/569125), and that won't make anything faster in the case of 1 NIC and 1 internet access. As far as I understand your setup (not much mentioned about it), your internet connection is the weak link - not your NIC.
But that's easy to find out if you want: just try to connect one or two more computers and then simultaneously start a speedtest on all machines - it will be half or third the bandwidth per computer that you can achieve with only one.